# How do I target the events column on my homepage

Tags: html, css

Im trying to change the link `text-decoration` only for the events column on my home page to `none` and trying to change the event details to a white color.

I've tried adding

```
.calendar-highlights .event-title a { 
   text-decoration: none !important; 
}
```

This doesn't work. As far as the font color for the event details go I'm completely stumped. Thank you!

http://partners.sbceo.org

Comment: @ Color - Have you tried `.event-details, .event-details .venue {
color: #FFF;
}` ?

Comment: Also check out the DevTools (CTRL+F12 in Chrome) to see what rules are taking precedence (and why).

Comment: Please add the relevant markup to your questions, so it remains relevant for others after your issue is fixed.

Comment: got it to work with the following                                 calendar-highlights .event-details,
.calendar-highlights .event-details {
 color: #ffffff;
}

calendar-highlights .event-details,
.calendar-highlights .event-title a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #E7C75B;
}

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: There seem to be a 'custom-css' file that overwrites your homepage styles. If you can create a new standalone css file, then I suggest adding it after the 'custom-css' file in order for the former to take precedence on the other one:

```
.calendar-highlights .event-title a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.event-details, .calendar-highlights span.venue{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Casey, I wasn't really aware of that. New notions acknowledged. Learned something new yet again!